# How to set the default program to open a certain file type in a certain folder?

Tags: default-programs, xdg, file-type

As well as being a Panda I am also an artist, I make my artwork mostly in GIMP and save my pictures to a certain directory on my computer. However I have a slight inconvenience because I save my images in `jpeg` format, however the default program to open `jpeg`s is the `Image Viewer`, and if I change it to `GIMP` for convenience with my artwork, it means that all the other `jpeg`s on my computer open in `GIMP`, and I don't want them to so this is where the problem begins...

So I am wondering if there is any way to make it so that all `jpeg`s opened in that certain directory on my computer open in `GIMP`, but all other `jpeg`s elsewhere open in the `Image Viewer`?

Comment: Only for Nautilus/Files or also for `xdg-open`?

Comment: @A.B.: I would say both if that can be done.

Comment: For `xdg-open` in a terminal you'd have to change the mimetype of your images.

Comment: Or you could also use the script in my answer with the complete image path.

Comment: Never use `.jpeg` as an intermediate format! It incurs [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss). Why don't you just save the images as `.xcf`, which is always automatically opened with GIMP?

Comment: @leftaroundabout: I don't use it as an intermediate format, it is the final format. However when I want to show someone my artwork it is lower quality if I open it in Image Viewer (the program I want to open everything else in) than it is in GIMP, so I prefer to open them in GIMP. That's why I want this folder to have images opening in GIMP and Image Viewer elsewhere (GIMP takes a while to start up so I don't want it for other images as I don't need them so high quality).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need a `desktop` file, and a wrapper script:

1. The `desktop` file

   - Create a desktop file

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/applications/jpeg-wrapper.desktop
     ```
   - Add the configuration below (change the property for `Name`)

     ```
     [Desktop Entry]
     Name=Special or Standard
     Comment=Open a JPEG depending of the path
     Exec=/home/user/bin/jpeg-wrapper %f
     Icon=
     Terminal=false
     Type=Application
     Categories=Editor;
     StartupNotify=true
     MimeType=image/jpeg;
     ```
   - Replace `user` in `Exec=/home/user/bin/jpeg-wrapper %f` with your username, the output of

     ```
     echo $USER
     ```
   - Replace the icon name in `Icon=` with a name or path of your choice
   - Use `MimeType=image/jpeg` to specify the mime types of files for which the decision is to apply. Separate multiple mime types via `;`

     Get the mime type via

     ```
     mimetype your_file
     ```

     e.g. for a text file

     ```
     text/plain
     ```
2. The wrapper script

   - Create a new script

     ```
     mkdir -p ~/bin
     nano ~/bin/jpeg-wrapper
     ```
   - Add the code below

     ```bsh
     #!/usr/bin/env bash
     image_path=$(dirname "$1")
     my_special_path="$HOME/tmp"
     open_with_special="gimp"
     open_with_standard="eog"

     if [[ $(mimetype -b "$1") == "image/jpeg" ]] && [[ "$image_path" == "$my_special_path"* ]]; then
             "$open_with_special" "$1"
     else
             "$open_with_standard" "$1"
     fi
     ```
   - Change `my_special_path` to your *artwork* folder. All subfolders are also considered.
   - Change `open_with_special` to your *special* application (e.g. `gimp`)
   - Make your wrapper script executable

     ```
     chmod +x ~/bin/jpeg-wrapper
     ```
3. Restart Unity/GNOME Shell, for the GNOME Shell e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, type `r` and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Associate one or more file types with the desktop file

   - Open your file manager and right click on a file for which the decision is to apply
   - Click <kbd>Properties</kbd>
   - Activate the tab <kbd>Open With</kbd>
   - Select the entry <kbd>Special or Standard</kbd>
   - Click <kbd>Set as default</kbd>
5. Enjoy **;)**

<sup>Script checked [here](http://www.shellcheck.net/).</sup>

Comment: Does it matter what I change the `Name` value to?

Comment: No, change the name as you would like.

Comment: Also, your script has a slight problem... Uhm... All the files in my artwork folder now open fine in GIMP, and the same for all subdirectories, however if a file is not in that area, it just does not open at all.

Comment: Let me check it.

Comment: Ok, it works fine now that you removed the infinite loop. ;)

Comment: You should probably loop on `$@` instead of running on just `$1`. Also, why the `exit 0`? O.o

Comment: @muru `exit 0` removed. A loop isn't necessary, I hope. I use `%f` in the desktop file.